# How Can I get the data from one domain to another domain using ajax jsonp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

EX: My site url `"http://localhost:54887/CustomOrdering.html"` but I want to get data from another site `"http://localhost:27746/Orders.aspx"`.For this I wrote in `CustomOrdering.html`

```
function SessionLogin() {                    
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    async: false,
                    url: 'http://localhost:27746/Orders.aspx/SessionLogin',                       
                    success: function (msg) {
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(errorThrown);
                    }
                }); 
            }
```

In **Orders.aspx**

```
 public  void SessionLogin()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(qs+ "( [{ \"x\": 10, \"y\": 15}] )");
    }
```

I am getting the error `jQuery11110002214477863162756_1449484451326 was not called`and showing error message in console 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <' and click on it pointing to Orders.aspx design page starting' [error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJJtr.png)

Comment: @nalini url you are calling in ur method is different from the site which you mentioned in your qstion

Comment: Can you Plz check this and plz suggest me...

Comment: Can you plz suggest me is it possible to call or not?. I am trying from 5 days and posting from 3 days. Even I didn't get any one solution?

Comment: An "unexpected token" is likely some illegal character code. Such a code is likely not to show up when you print to console. Therefore, print out the string one character at a time or use a protocol analyzer or debugger etc. to see the actual bytes of the string.

Comment: since the call is being made from one domain to other, do you have CORS enabled at Orders.aspx?

Comment: @Awais I don't know  how is that. Can you please provide me full details?

Comment: I tried by settings in web.config file  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration> but no use.

Answer (score 0):

The other server needs to wrap the return value with your given callback name:

```
 public  void SessionLogin()
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        string qs = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["callback"];
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write( qs + "( [{ \"x\": 10, \"y\": 15}] )");
    }
```

Comment: I tried with this not getting. showing same  error message

Comment: Hi, Can you plz help me to find out the issue?